# Rsync/Copy certain file extensions stripping folders

Tags: linux, bash, files, rsync, cp

I have a bunch of folders with sub directories please see below

```
Books

-- Temp1.nfo

-- Temp2.txt

-- Temp3.doc


Books 2

-- Temp4.nfo

-- Temp5.txt

-- Temp6.doc
```

I want to copy the txt and doc file extensions and place them into one directory. An example

```
Final

--Temp2.txt

--Temp3.doc

 --Temp5.txt

--Temp6.doc
```

I was able to get this done with a cp command. The issue is I am unable to see the status or do a dry run.

```
 cp -u **/{*.mkv,*mp4,*avi} /home/joedoe/Books/
```

Is anyone able to assist me with coming up with an rsync command that does this?

Comment: How about the `.nfo` files... do u want to remove in "Books" or should move to "Books2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rsync` SRC DEST syntax is very similar to the `cp` SRC DEST syntax, so you could use something like

```
rsync -auv */*.{txt,doc} /home/joedoe/Books/
```

to copy all *.txt and *.doc files to the target directory.

Options:

- `-a` archive mode (shortcut for `-rlptgoD`)
- `-u` skip files that are newer on the receiver (like `cp -u`)
- `-v` increase verbosity

Since the archive option `-a` also includes the recursive `-r` option, you could disable this flag with an additional `--no-r` 
if you want (`-a` would also copy a directory `Book/my.doc/` since it would match the `*.doc` pattern and `-a --no-r` 
would disable the recursion).

The output with `--dry-run` would look like this:

```
$ rsync --dry-run -auv */*.{txt,doc} /home/joedoe/Books/
sending incremental file list
created directory /home/joedoe/Books
Temp2.txt
Temp3.doc
Temp5.txt
Temp6.doc

sent 221 bytes  received 69 bytes  580.00 bytes/sec
total size is 11  speedup is 0.04 (DRY RUN)
```

You can add multiple `-v` arguments to get more verbose output like `-vv` or `-vvv`.

Comment: This worked thank you!